# Record video via AVFoundation in iOS

Tags: objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I try to create an application that records video and takes images at receiving a message via sockets.
What I do not arrive to do is video recording using **AVFoundation**.
is that because of the fact that I use a single session ?
Here is my code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Parser.h"
#import "DeviceConfig.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // z-index
    _vImage.layer.zPosition = 1;
    _toggle.layer.zPosition = 1;
    recording = NO;
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.0.103", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
    input = (__bridge NSInputStream*) readStream;
    output = (__bridge NSOutputStream*) writeStream;

    [input setDelegate: self];
    [output setDelegate: self];

    [input scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [output scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [input open];
    [output open];
}

- (void) sendMessage : (NSString*) message {
    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iam:%@", message];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [output write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}

- (void) stream : (NSStream*) theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent) streamEvent {
    switch(streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            [self openCamera];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            NSLog(@"kayn");
            if(theStream == input) {
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int length;
                while([input hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    length = [input read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if(length > 0) {
                        NSString* outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:length encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                        // To split different messages sended in buffer via Socket (in one message)
                        NSArray *options = [[outputString substringToIndex:[outputString length] - 1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
                        NSLog(@"%@", options);
                        if(outputString != nil) {
                            if([options[1] isEqualToString:@"TAKE_PIC"]) {
                                [self takePic];
                            }else if([options[1] isEqualToString:@"PARAMS"]) {
                                Parser* parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithXMLData: options[2]];
                                [self changeCameraConfig:[parser getCameraOptions]];
                            }else if([options[1] isEqualToString:@"REC_VIDEO"]) {
                                [self recordVideo];
                            }else{
                                [self showMessage:@"Unknow order, please contact the administrator."];
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}

- (void) showMessage : (NSString*) msg {
    UIAlertView *helloWorldAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"My First App" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Display the Hello World Message
    [helloWorldAlert show];
}

- (void) openCamera {
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    previewLayer.frame = self.liveCameraView.bounds;
    [self.liveCameraView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


    NSError *error = nil;

    deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    [session addInput:deviceInput];

    _stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    _videoOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

    [session addOutput:_videoOutput];

    [session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];

}

-(void) changeCameraConfig:(NSMutableDictionary *)config {
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    DeviceConfig* conf;
    for(id key in config) {

        conf = [config objectForKey:key];
        //[self showMessage:@"ok"];
        // Config Torch
        if([key isEqualToString:@"torch"]) {
            if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"on"]) {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            }else{
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            }
        }
        // Config Focus
        if([key isEqualToString:@"focus_mode"]) {
            if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"auto"]) {
                [device setFocusMode: AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
            }else if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"continous_auto"]) {
                [device setFocusMode: AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
            }else{
                [device setFocusMode: AVCaptureFocusModeLocked];
            }
        }
        // Config Flash
        if([key isEqualToString:@"flash"]) {
            if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"on"]) {
                [device setFlashMode: AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
            }else{
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
            }
        }
        // Config Exposure
        if([key isEqualToString:@"white_balance"]) {
            if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"auto"]) {
                [device setExposureMode: AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            }else if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"continous_auto"]) {
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
            }else if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"custom"]) {
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom];
            }else{
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
            }
        }
        // Config White balance
        if([key isEqualToString:@"exposure_mode"]) {
            if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"auto"]) {
                [device setExposureMode: AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
            }else if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"continous_auto"]) {
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
            }else if([[conf curValue] isEqualToString: @"custom"]) {
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom];
            }else{
                [device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
            }
        }
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}

-(void) takePic {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in _stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", _stillImageOutput);
    [_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"no attachments");

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         self.vImage.image = image;
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
     }];
}

- (AVCaptureDevice *) CameraWithPosition:(AVCaptureDevicePosition) Position
{
    NSArray *Devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *Device in Devices)
    {
        if ([Device position] == Position)
        {
            return Device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

/*
 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

- (IBAction)toggleCam:(id)sender {
    AVCaptureDeviceInput* newDeviceInput;
    NSError* error;
    AVCaptureDevicePosition position = [[deviceInput device] position];
    if(position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
        newDeviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self CameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack] error:&error];
    }else{
        newDeviceInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self CameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront] error:&error];
    }
    if(error != nil) {
        [session beginConfiguration];       //We can now change the inputs and output configuration.  Use commitConfiguration to end
        [session removeInput:deviceInput];
        if ([session canAddInput:newDeviceInput])
        {
            [session addInput:newDeviceInput];
            deviceInput = newDeviceInput;
        }
        else
        {
            [session addInput:deviceInput];
        }

        //Set the connection properties again
        //[self CameraSetOutputProperties];


        [session commitConfiguration];
    }

}

-(void) recordVideo {
    [self showMessage:@"recording .."];
    // If we are not recording
    if(!recording) {
        recording = YES;
        NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output_video.wav"];
        NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
        NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            NSError* errorMsg;
            if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&errorMsg] == NO)
            {
                //Error - handle if requried
            }
        }
        [_videoOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:self];
    }else{
        recording = NO;
        [_videoOutput stopRecording];
    }
}

-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {
    BOOL recordedSuccessfully = YES;
    if ([error code] != noErr) {
        // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value) {
            recordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }
    if(recordedSuccessfully) {
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        if([ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]) {
            if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL]) {
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                            completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {

                                                }
                                            }];
            }
        }else{
            [self showMessage:@"Error"];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: I want to record video using AVFoundation

Comment: And you want someone to go through all that code and find out where it's not working?  It's not going to happen.

Comment: Haha you are right, the target code is in recordVideo function and delegate methods captureOutput.

Comment: Ask more a precise question; find out what's not working and provide a short code snippet.  Someone might be able to help you then.

Comment: the target code is in recordVideo function and delegate method captureOutput.